Unexpected ST_Distance with sinusoidal projection in PostGIS
In R, if I do
library(fields)
library(mapproj)

radius.of.earth = 6371 ## in kilometers or 3959 miles

#New York-New Orleans example
NY <- c(-73.97,40.78)
NO <- c(-90.25,29.98)
newloc <- rbind(NY,NO)

NYNO.geodesic <- rdist.earth(newloc, miles=FALSE)[2,1]
NYNO.sinusoidal <- mapproject(c(NY[1],NO[1]),c(NY[2],NO[2]),projection="sinusoidal")
NYNO.sinusoidal.loc <- cbind(NYNO.sinusoidal$x,NYNO.sinusoidal$y)
NYNO.sinusoidal.dist <- rdist(NYNO.sinusoidal.loc)[2,1]*radius.of.earth

print(paste("geodesic: ", NYNO.geodesic, "sinusoidal: ", NYNO.sinusoidal.dist));

i get
geodesic: 1899.41484880661 sinusoidal: 1897.71439713851
a negligible difference.
However in PostGIS if i do
SELECT ST_Distance(
        'SRID=4326;POINT(-73.97 40.78)'::geography, -- new york
        'SRID=4326;POINT(-90.25 29.98)'::geography -- new orleans
       )/1000 geodesic,
       ST_Distance(
        ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(-73.97 40.78)'::geometry, 54008 /* World_Sinusoidal */), -- new york
        ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(-90.25 29.98)'::geometry, 54008 /* World_Sinusoidal */) -- new orleans
       )/1000 sinusoidal;

i get
|-----------------|-------------------|
|         geodesic|         sinusoidal|
|-----------------|-------------------|
| 1898.08516037479| 2741.2605637667175|
|-----------------|-------------------|

a massive difference.
I'm pretty sure the R results are correct, what do I have wrong in PostGIS?

I believe they are not the same projections, please take a look at this thread https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-devel/2018-January/026807.html

@TimothyDalton close... they are using the same projection but apply different orientations. see my answer below.

As it turns out, the PostGIS query is correct, and the PostGIS results are correct and expected. The mapproject results are also correct but unexpected because mapproject applies a tailored rotation to the projection for each call.
I debugged mapproject and found that it applies an orientation of c(90, 0, -82.11). The rotation of -82.11 is the mean of the two longitudes.
Using an explicit orientation with the above mentioned rotation:
NYNO.sinusoidal <- mapproject(c(NY[1],NO[1]),c(NY[2],NO[2]),projection="sinusoidal", orientation=c(90,0,-82.11))
indeed produces the same result as the default: 1897.714.
Explicitly removing the auto calculated rotation by using:
NYNO.sinusoidal <- mapproject(c(NY[1],NO[1]),c(NY[2],NO[2]),projection="sinusoidal", orientation=c(90,0,0))
produces a near identical result as PostGIS of 2741.416 (vs PostGIS with 2741.260).
Bottom line: PostGIS uses the orientation specified by the SRID, while mapproject uses a tailored orientation based on the supplied coordinates, resulting in a different distance.

As documented in https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html, PostGIS computes Cartesian distance for geometry types, and geodesic distance for geography types.

For geometry types returns the minimum 2D Cartesian (planar) distance
between two geometries, in projected units (spatial ref units).
For geography types defaults to return the minimum geodesic distance
between two geographies in meters, compute on the spheroid determined
by the SRID. If use_spheroid is false, a faster spherical calculation
is used.

Step by step:

convert lon-lat points with ST_Transform into 54008 and you'll have

"POINT(-6244126.92225917 4516141.899089543)" and
"POINT(-8709632.36505315 3317896.352460691)"

Apply the Pythagorean equation a^2 + b^2 = c^2. I inserted the values into Excel and got
2741260.56376672 as a result, and that matches with PostGIS.

